# Group and order array of objects in php by string value

Tags: php, sorting, usort

I have an array of objects which looks like this, note that they are already ordered by create_time via MYSQL:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[38]
      public 'vacancy_id' => int 5
      public 'title' => string 'test title' (length=10)
      public 'create_time' => string '2018-10-05 11:15:34' (length=19)
      public 'language_iso' => string 'NL' (length=2)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[42]
      public 'vacancy_id' => int 9
      public 'title' => string 'test title 5' (length=12)
      public 'create_time' => string '2018-08-05 11:15:34' (length=19)
      public 'language_iso' => string 'EN' (length=2)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[40]
      public 'vacancy_id' => int 7
      public 'title' => string 'test title 3' (length=12)
      public 'create_time' => string '2018-08-05 11:15:34' (length=19)
      public 'language_iso' => string 'FR' (length=2)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[39]
      public 'vacancy_id' => int 6
      public 'title' => string 'test title 2' (length=12)
      public 'create_time' => string '2018-06-05 11:15:34' (length=19)
      public 'language_iso' => string 'FR' (length=2)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[41]
      public 'vacancy_id' => int 8
      public 'title' => string 'test title 4' (length=12)
      public 'create_time' => string '2018-02-05 11:15:34' (length=19)
      public 'language_iso' => string 'NL' (length=2)
```

On my page I am implementing a sorting functionality. There's (for now) 4 sorting options:

- By create_time (this is the default sort as well, as done in MySQL. And I always want to keep this sort).
- By NL language iso
- By FR language iso
- By EN language iso

In the array example as given above, let's say I want to sort by "FR language iso". This means that I want my result set to look like this:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[40]
      public 'vacancy_id' => int 7
      public 'title' => string 'test title 3' (length=12)
      public 'create_time' => string '2018-08-05 11:15:34' (length=19)
      public 'language_iso' => string 'FR' (length=2)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[39]
      public 'vacancy_id' => int 6
      public 'title' => string 'test title 2' (length=12)
      public 'create_time' => string '2018-06-05 11:15:34' (length=19)
      public 'language_iso' => string 'FR' (length=2)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[38]
      public 'vacancy_id' => int 5
      public 'title' => string 'test title' (length=10)
      public 'create_time' => string '2018-10-05 11:15:34' (length=19)
      public 'language_iso' => string 'NL' (length=2)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[42]
      public 'vacancy_id' => int 9
      public 'title' => string 'test title 5' (length=12)
      public 'create_time' => string '2018-08-05 11:15:34' (length=19)
      public 'language_iso' => string 'EN' (length=2)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[41]
      public 'vacancy_id' => int 8
      public 'title' => string 'test title 4' (length=12)
      public 'create_time' => string '2018-02-05 11:15:34' (length=19)
      public 'language_iso' => string 'NL' (length=2)
```

So in this example, the result must contain:

- Results with language_iso FR on top, but still within them, sorted by create_time
- Results with language_iso EN and NL go under the FR results, but also within them, sorted by create_time

I've been completely running blank using a custom function in php's usort function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (and probably should) handle this sorting requirement completely from MySQL:

```
SELECT vacancy_id, title, create_time, language_iso
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    IF(language_iso = 'FR', 0, 1),
    create_time;
```

The above `ORDER BY` clause would cover French language records coming first, followed by all other languages, with the `create_time` covering the sorting as a second step.

While you *could* try to sort a given array/result set inside PHP, in practice you might want to always query, as the underlying data could become stale.

Comment: This solves the problem perfectly! I had been searching for a mysql solution before but I couldnt find it and thought it would be easier to solve in php. Turns out I was so wrong! Thanks again for the very simple solution.

Comment: @Dennis If you have more complex requirement, and want to order each language in a certain order, then consider using `FIELD`, e.g. `ORDER BY FIELD(language_iso, 'FR', 'EN', 'NL')`, which would put French before English, before Netherlands.